# Rails POST method from two separate pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form for the same controller and action on two different pages and want the validation on the model to apply in both locations but I cant seem to get the render/redirect to work for both.

The default controller:

```
def create
  @job = Job.new(job_params)

  if @job.save
    redirect_back fallback_location: jobs_path, flash: { success: 'New job was added.' }
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

This works when a new job is added, but if it fails it will always redirect back to the `jobs/new` route.

I have tried using the redirect_back method but this does not show the validation and current values are lost. I have had a play with looking at the referrer path and trying to extract the controller and method and re-render that but I have not had much success.

I would like to avoid having to add custom logic for each route and dont want a new action for each page I want to be able to create a job on.

Comment: Your actual problem is you lost your data when when validation error occurs, am I right ?

Comment: @PradeepSapkota sort of. Using the default action the data remains but I always end up on the /jobs/new route after failed validation. Using a redirect solution I end up on the right page but the data and validation do not render. So I need a hybrid of the two solutions.

Comment: Can you post your form and then job_params def ?

Comment: Save the validation errors into the `flash` hash, this will make them available after the redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I used Ryan's suggestion and set up a JS response. Posting here for future readers.

Controller:

```
# app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb
def create
  @job = Job.new(job_params)

  if @job.save
    redirect_back fallback_location: jobs_path, flash: { success: 'New job was added.' }
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :new }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

View:

```
# app/views/jobs/create.js.erb
var errors = <%= raw @job.errors.to_json %>;
validation.parseErrors('job', errors);
```

JS:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/client_validation/client_validation.coffee
@validation =
  parseErrors: (model, errors)->
    validation.clearErrors()
    for field, errorList of errors
      $field = $ "\##{model}_#{field}"
      $field.closest('.form-group').addClass 'has-danger'
      for error in errorList
        $field.after "<div class='form-control-feedback'>#{field} #{error}</div>"
  clearErrors: ->
    $('.has-danger').removeClass 'has-danger'
    $('.form-control-feedback').remove()
```

I am still not certain that this is the right way of doing this but it works quite nicely and much better than a simple js alert.

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually do this is by submitting the form via `JavaScript`. That way, if it fails, I can just render an `alert()` with whatever error message there is. The values are still there (as I haven't left the page). If it succeeds, I just issue a `window.location` to the next page I want to go.

To do that, add the `remote: true` option to your `form_for`/`form_tag`. Then in your controller:

```
if @job.save
  render js: "window.location = 'new/path/after/save'"
else
  render js: "alert(\"#{@job.errors.full_messages.first}\")"
end
```

Comment: Not my ideal solution. I am using simple_form which displays validation errors on page render, using a js solution would require me to use a js solution for validation which I would rather not do.